# How can I close browser if a specific URL is entered?

Tags: browser, task, scheduler, using, kill

How to Close browser (Google Chrome) if a specific URL is entered on Windows 10 using Task Scheduler?

Comment: It's quite difficult to force the web browser to close based on URL input(and it can be bypassed in many ways). I recommend editing the `hosts` file to prevent access to specific sites.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Biut I see that this website ("Venge.io") does not get blocked even if its entered in the hosts file

Comment: How did you edit the hosts file? valid hosts rule is like: `127.0.0.1 venge.io`

Answer (score 0):

Well, for children, use an [app for child management through Microsoft](https://account.microsoft.com/family/about), which allows complete control over browsing websites, apps and screen time. The user can ask for permission to use the site but cannot visit it until approved. You can reject/ignore the request and they still can't get in. There's more, check it out!